# CollectionView doesn't display when i run the app

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

I created this collectionView [image]

already filled with different elements in my storyboard, and this is the viewController where the collectionView is

```
 import UIKit

    class CollectionClass: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

    }
```

now i'm trying to run the app but the collectionView is not displayed why?

Comment: Did you set your datasource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
if there is only three cells this code is ok

```
import UIKit

class CollectionClass: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        CollectionView.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1 // number of section

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 5 //number of items 

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cellId = String()
    switch(indexPath.row) {
         case 0: cellId = "cellidOne"
         case 1: cellId = "cellidTwo"
         case 2: cellID = "cellidThree" 
    }
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: there is only one problem i have three cells in my collectionView so how can i add the identifier, let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "yourcellID", for: indexPath) ?  something like this is good if i have only one cell with is own identifier but in my case?